# gwt-dispatch - command pattern alternative for GWT

Tags: gwt, command-pattern, gwt-dispatch

#### Is there alternative to [gwt-dispatch](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) to be used in GWT project?

Comment: Just curious, why are you looking for alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GWT-Platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) has a [Dispatch-Module](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch).

Comment: I'm not familiar with mvp4g, only gwt-p. Can't help you there, sorry.

Comment: GWTP's dispatcher is available in a separate jar that does not depend on GWTP's MVP, you can definitely use it with mvp4g.

Comment: @PhilippeBeaudoin -  I just could not understand how gwtp works. Google MVP with Activities and Places came so naturally to me. It took just a week for me to setup a project with Activities and Places. May be I'm not good in Java to understand GWTP's 'not-java-like' way of doing things. An API should be simple to use. That attracts more developers. Experts can find their way anyway.