# Is GWT-Dispatch still used?

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt

I've read about Command pattern, and how to implement it in GWT.

So, I've found gwt-dispatch api, but, i don't know how to use it. The examples from the wiki don't work.

Is better I implement my own simple Action/Result interfaces and my own commands, or someone have a example that works with dispatch?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GWT-Platform ( http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/ )

It's complex MVP framework and has it's own good dispatch implementation, manual here:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStartedDispatch

related question: [gwt-dispatch - command pattern alternative for GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290836/gwt-dispatch-command-pattern-alternative-for-gwt)

Answer (score 0):

I found, the same as you, that gwt-dispatch seemed to have fallen into disuse. I hunted around for alternatives.

In the end, I settled on Tessell. I have since had a good experience using [Tessell's dispatch component](http://www.tessell.org/dispatch.html). Tessell has various components … I have not used the others, but have found its dispatch component works well for me, and the annotations it provides save quite a bit of typing :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have tried this sample, and it works in my environment. You can also try this:
https://github.com/rombert/gwt-dispatch-sample

`gwt-dispatch` source code:
https://github.com/randombits-org/gwt-dispatch